# Smooth scrolling html loaded large text files using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smooth-scrolling

I ran into a dead end when I came to know that I cant use **infinity.js** for infinite scrolling and yet not let the user feel slowness loading **>1gb** text files using javascript.

So what can I use to smooth the scrolling .(A jquery feature maybe).

**extra info :** 
I have a function that reads 1000 bytes until scroll down to bottom and it then reads another 1000 bytes again and so on.Blob function that is

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a code snippet or a jsfiddle? It will help people who read this question have a better understanding of your issue

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have sorted out the answer. Re using the DOM element solved the issue of slowness.